# Finding the elliptic function that maps a triangle to the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, periodic-functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

This is a task that my professor give me! I am thinking about finding the function by using the Christoffel-Weierstrass transformation. But he said that it's completely correct. We need to use the elliptic function constructed by Eisenstein and Kronecker with periods! I really do not know how to find its periods here!

I have difficulty with the problem follows:

> Find the elliptic function $\zeta(z)$ which maps the triangle $ABC$ (illustrated in the figure) to the circle, such that
> $$\begin{cases}
> \zeta(0)=1^+,\\
> \zeta(b)=1^-,\\
> \zeta(z_0)=0.
> \end{cases}$$
> [image]
> Finding the inverse function $z(\zeta)$ of that $\zeta(z)$.

Thanks a lot to you for watching!

Comment: Please let us know the source of the problem as well your own ideas towards a solution. Questions which are just problem statements are discouraged here.

Comment: This is a task that my professor give me! I am thinking about finding the function by using the Christoffel-Weierstrass transformation. But he said that it's completely correct. We need to use the elliptic function constructed by Eisenstein and Kronecker with periods! I really do not know how to find its periods here!

Comment: Yes, what was the answer? (You can answer your own question, there is no rule against it.)